# ActiveRecord Association - Design Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, model-associations

## Overview

I have a set of data models for a Sailing club example, where there are `Members` of the club, who have a relationship with a `Boat` (eg Owner, Skipper, Crew).  Currently wrestling with the best way to design the ActiveRecord associations to answer some questions on getting data.  This would include such queries as:

- A `Boat` has many `Members`,
- A `Member` can belong to one or more `Boats`
- A `Member` has one or more roles associated to a `Boat` (Skipper, Crew, Owner)

## First Design Attempt

So my first design was to have a `Boat` <- many to many -> `Member` structure using the has_many_through association type.  The join table would carry the attribute for the type of relationship with the `Boat` This looks like:

```
class Boat < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :boat_crews
    has_many :members, through: :boat_crews
end

class Member < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :boat_crews
    has_many :boats, through: :boat_crews
end

class BoatCrew < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :member
    belongs_to :boat
end
```

The table `BoatCrews` has the usual attributes `id, member_id, boat_id` and also includes another attribute called `role:string` to represent the relationship to the boat.  So when a `Member` is associated to a boat and entry is placed in the join table to hold the join information with the role.  If a `Member` is both and owner and say a skipper of the boat then there are two roles in the `BoatCrews` table.

Now what this enables is the expected ActiveRecord Association queries such as

```
b = Boat.find(1)
b.members # show all the members associated with the first Boat
```

The only downside is that if a `Member` has two roles (Owner, Skipper) then the `b.members` query will return an array which contains one duplicate (ie. the Member with two roles).  This can be removed with a `b.members.uniq`

Is there a better design where I model the role/relationship to the Boat differently, hence Design attempt number 2

## Second Design Attempt

Thinking on it some more I thought that I could seperate the idea of the member and the relationship to the concept of a boat and a generic crew.  So new model attempt is

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :crew
end

class Crew < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :boat_crews
    has_many :boats, through: :boat_crews

    belongs_to :member, optional: true
end

class Boat < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :boat_crews
    has_many :crews, through: :boat_crews
end

class BoatCrew < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :boat
  belongs_to :crew
end
```

The idea is that a `Boat` has a `Crew` collection and vice versa with the `Crew` model identifying the type of `Crew` role (eg crew, skipper, owner).  The association of the `Member` to `Crew` models is to then take the `Member` information (eg name, etc) and associate to the role they have with the `Boat` crew model.

The flaw in this design is that the **has-one** relationship defined between the `Member` and `Crew` models means that foreign_key faults occur if you try to do a **member#crew.build** type creation.

## Is there a better option

At this point neither approach seems correct.  The first design works, but requires use of an additional constraint (needing to use `uniq` method).  The second design doesn't work and on reflection is probably correct in that the semantics I've defined is 'has-one' but I'm really got more than one (eg `Member` has two roles as part of `Boat`).

**Some ideas I've thought about are**

- Revert to the ***Boat has_many Member*** with a join table and then use a new model from that join table to model the type of relationship
- Does introducing a model off a join table introduce too many levels of indirection ?

So seeking any suggestions or comments on how to tackle this one ?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, I don't think your design attempt 2 solves for the 'problem' that arises with design attempt 1. If a member can only have one 'crew', then they would still be doubly counted when being considered a part of a boatcrew, now you have a duplicate crew (that points to the same member).

Though this isn't a *perfect* rule, when doing initial architecture, it's a decent rule-of-thumb to model things as close to the real world as you can. Optimizations can come later. In this case, I would go with attempt 1, but don't use `uniq` (because that would require loading everything into ruby, and then getting distinct record, which is slow). Rely on rails [Active Record Query Interface](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) instead. You can use something like,

```
b.members.distinct
```

which generates a `SELECT DISTINCT ...` query for when you need unique members. Realistically though, it's highly likely you want to query for knowledge of the members and their roles. I'm not sure of the easiest way to do this in pure rails active query interface, but, you can always use [array_agg](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/postgresql-array_agg-function/) if you want to get the member and all of their roles.

For example

```
SELECT members.name, array_agg(boat_crews.role) AS roles FROM members
INNER JOIN boat_crews on members.id = boat_crews.member_id
INNER JOIN boats on boat_crews.boat_id = boats.id
WHERE boats.id = 1
GROUP BY members.name
```

would return something like

```
names | roles
joe   | ["rower"]
john  | ["skipper","captain"]
```

Will get you the names of all members, and all of their respective roles as an array. I leave it to you to convert this to an active record query.

A rather long-winded way of saying go with option 1, and ask specific questions here when you need help with certain queries.